# MacOs 11.5: Double clicking an application works, but running through terminal doesn't

Tags: macos, applications

I installed the analysis software root from the `pkg` file. I can find the executable using `Finder`. If I double click on that, the program works, however if I navigate there through the terminal and execute it I get the following:

```
$ cd /Applications/root_v6.24.06/bin/
$ root
roots: insufficient input: client URL must to be provided
```

Any idea on how to solve that?

Note: I'm new to Mac but have been a Linux user for some time.

Comment: Well that won't work in Linux either. An executable must be on your PATH or provide a directory as part of the executable. You can  just use the executable name when it is in your current directory.

Comment: Note the error reported is for roots not root. Rotts is a different executable that. Is on your path

Comment: Can you, from the Finder, drag the program to the terminal, then valid by Enter?

Comment: @Jean_JD: Hmmm That actually worked. So `$ /Applications/root_v6.24.06/bin/root` works but `$ cd /Applications/root_v6.24.06/bin/ $ root` doesn't. Strange!

Comment: @Thanos you'd have to use ./root if you're already in the directory, otherwise it would look for the root command in your default paths for cmds

Comment: @KevinGrabher I know, but it gives me `./root: can't start ROOT -- check that /Applications/root_v6.24.06/bin/bin/root.exe exists!`

Comment: That sounds like a bug in the "root" software, since ".exe" would suggest a Windows executable?

Comment: My guess would be that their software is manipulating the `$0` to work out where to find its other components. You could try going back a folder and running `./bin/root` instead, but it may just be that you need to set `ROOTSYS` to `/Applications/root_v6.24.06` via `export ROOTSYS=/Applications/root_v6.24.06`

Comment: @chymb: That's interesting. Doing `./bin/root works`! I'll get in touch with `root` people. Thanks!